# Parabolic sine-Gordon equation with periodic and odd initial data function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, periodic-functions, even-and-odd-functions

Consider the following parabolic equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u = \partial_{xx}u + \sin u,\ (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty), \\
u(x,0) = u_0(x),
\end{cases}
$$
in which $u_0(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $2\pi$-periodic and odd.

I want to know how to derive the solution $u$ itself is also $2\pi$-periodic and odd for each $t>0$. Any hint?

Comment: Is there a reason you think that a closed form exists for general initial conditions? Even the steady state equation barely has a closed form representation in term of elliptic integrals

Comment: Can you provide some references about the steady state equation?@whpowell96

Comment: Idk about a specific reference but you can reduce it to a first order equation by multiplying through by $u_x$ and integrating. WolframAlpha gives the formulation in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions or something similar.